# How to combine Automation Tests that use different runners and platforms?

Tags: automated-tests, system-testing

Is there a way (tools or solutions) to combine different suites for different technologies without writing your own test runner?

I already have tests for different components of the system (Android, Web, back-end) but now I need to **combine them into a single suite**. Test suites must run in a specific order (e.g *Android test* send data than *Web test* validate is data displayed correctly), so it would be nice to have a possibility to write config like that:

```
const superMegaSuite = [
    { type: 'TestNG', suite: 'SendData' },
    { type: 'Karma', suite: 'Check My Data' },
];
```

Technology that used for testing and need to be "combined":

- [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/index.html) + [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) + [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) (for web)
- [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/index.html) + [Appium](http://appium.io/) (for Android)

*P.S.* I understand that technically task could be resolved with writing some custom runner that will be an abstraction over existing runners. However, I want to avoid writing my own implementation if there already exists some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Outthentic](https://github.com/melezhik/outthentic). I am not sure if I understand the specific of you project perfect, but you may go like this:

```
$ cat hook.bash

run_story SendData
run_story CheckMyData

$ cat modules/SendData/story.bash

echo run send data suite

$ cat modules/CheckMyData/story.bash

echo run check my data suite
```

So you can organize different types of tests into stories and run them in order:

```
$ strun

2018-08-14 18:31:47 :  [path] modules/SendData/
run send data suite
ok      scenario succeeded
2018-08-14 18:31:47 :  [path] modules/CheckMyData/
run check my data suite
ok      scenario succeeded
STATUS  SUCCEED
```